# Where to initialize a GraphQL Client inside Django App

Tags: python, django, graphql

I'm building an API with Django, I want to query the Github GraphQL API, and I found this [GraphQL client](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) for python that suits my needs.

But now, I'm wondering, where is the proper place to initialize such a client inside my Django App? inside the request? in the apps.py? in views.py? any guidelines will be appreciated! here is my current Django Project folder structure:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── portfolio
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer to this post.
https://medium.com/swlh/introduction-to-graphql-using-django-ca7058006574

Comment: hey! thanks for the suggestion! but i think this is not what im looking for, if you read closely, im not building a GraphQL API but Querying one (The Github v4 API) from a Django Request. The library i mentioned is a GraphQL Client for Python, and it must be initialized, but init a new instance of the client everytime a request comes in sounds unnecessary, so i feel theremust be a better place for init the library, and later import the already init client to a view

Comment: Can't say if it's the most Djangoish way, but I would put it in views.py. If you use the client in only one view, then I'd both import and initialize the client inside that views function/class.

Comment: Hello! I was thinking about that, but I read out there that views.py gots imported per request on the workers, maybe i understand wrong? if that is the case, maybe it will not be different from init it on the request itself

Comment: Why do you need the query to be made in the server-side?

Comment: I want to preprocess the query results for easy consumption, maybe this is overkill, but I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: instantiate ***new client right in the view method*** = new client for each request. (good option - overriding [`initial`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#initialself-request-42args-kwargs) view method). Improve later.

---

**It depends.**

If there are no request / user options for the client (= client is **the same** *for every request / user*):

1. import one from submodule as @ElPapi42 suggested (= same as instantiate new client in views.py globally, not as part of method logic)
2. or instantiate new client right in the view method - new client for each request

If there are request / user specific options (i.e. client need to have `request.user` specific options / credentials):

2. instantiate new client right in the view method

---

Option 1 - Client is instantiated once per worker view. Although it provides some performance benefits they are subtle and obscured:

- you may not know what it means: shared client => possibly use methods that modify client state for different requests / users that rely on the state
- worker lifetime is (should be) actually not that long
- hard to assess performance benefits with hard to assess proper implementation

In reality you may want to connect to github with some current `request.user` specific options, perform multiple requests (= cookies may be involved and auto-added in subsequent requests => client cannot be shared with multiple users) = at least separate client for each user.

Answer (score 1):

As per definition a graphql client needs it's own configuration, modules and error handling I would suggest you to create a namespace adjacent to your other projects. Django uses the concept of [Applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#module-django.apps) which is providing seperated configuration, logging and error handling for this case. You define additional Applications in your project in your `settings.py` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#installed-apps)). Your project structure would then look smth like:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── graphql-client
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── client.py
│   ├── ressources
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── ├── repository.py
│   │   └── user.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── views.py
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── portfolio
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

Comment: Hello! I will use my GraphQL Client inside my /api Django App, can you suggest some alternative that keeps my /api Application fully independent? that way, it can be moved between projects without hassle.

Comment: The location in your project structure is up to your preference. Also then you can stick to django `Application` concept just by initializing it in your namespace. (`api.graphql-client`)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a python module in the `/api` Application called `graphql.py` that init the graphql client. from here, it is easily importable.

I decide not to create a separate Django Application for this because that will be overkill on this context, due to the simplicity of the code:

in `graphql.py`:

```py
from gql import Client
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport
from django.conf import settings

# Instaciate a graphql client
client = Client(
    transport=RequestsHTTPTransport(
        url='https://api.github.com/graphql',
        headers={'Authorization': 'bearer {token}'.format(token=settings.GITHUB_TOKEN)},
        verify=False,
        retries=3,
    ),
    fetch_schema_from_transport=True,
)
```